# Solving math expressions using java

Tags: java, eclipse, math

I want to be able to let the user choose what he/she wants to do , then at the end of code add, subtract, divide or multiply the users responses. How would i go about doing so? Using an `if` statement it says, cannot convert string userinput to `boolean`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Would you like to addition subtract divide or multiply? ");
        String userinput = kboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("enter the first number ");
        String firstnumber = kboard.nextLine();
        String s1 = firstnumber;
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        System.out.print("enter the second number ");
        String secondnumber = kboard.nextLine();
        String s2 = secondnumber;
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        if (userinput) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `userinput` is string which is why you are getting the error. think what do you want `userinput` to be so if condition evaluates to true and add that to the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `switch` for this. (you can use String in the argument too)

Pseudo code:

```
switch(userinput) {
case "multiply"   : //multiply code here
      break;
case "subtraction": //subtraction code here
      break; 
... //and so on
default: // executes when user puts in wrong input
      break;
}
```

It is important to use `break` after each case, otherwise all cases will be executed in top-down manner.

Also there is a lot of useless code in your project.You can reduce this:

```
   String firstnumber = kboard.nextLine();
   String s1 = firstnumber;
   int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
```

To this:

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(kboard.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `if` statement, what you are doing is illogical.

However, to compare `Strings` in `Java`, you must use the following prescribed formats:

```
if(userinput.equals("texttocompare"))
//or
if(userinput.equals(variabletocompare)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
    if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("multiply")) {
        answer = n1 * n2;
        System.out.println(answer);
    } else if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("divide")) {

    answer = n1 / n2;
    System.out.println(answer);

    }
```